# What does the tilde between two words mean on Pealim?

Tags: hebrew

Examples are like [this](https://www.pealim.com/dict/9106-muchtzan/): `מֻחְצֶנֶת ~ מוחצנת`. What does it mean that there are two words under each header?

Comment: Alternative spellings: defective and plene.

Comment: @Keelan specifically defective pointed and plene unpointed. The same word could also be written defective and unpointed as מחצנת or plene and pointed as מוּחְצֶנֶת, although the two spellings in the OP would certainly be the two most common ones

Comment: Pealim seems primarily directed at modern Hebrew speakers, and in Modern Hebrew where things aren't vowelized in writing they often add vowel letters to make it clear what word is intended. Eg מדַבר and מדֻבר would be spelled the same if you took the vowel markers off, or you could spell the later מדובר with וּ replacing the equivalent ֻ" "   in order to make it clearer - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mater_lectionis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative spellings of the same term. You could write "color~colour" in an English dictionary for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

While those *are* two different spellings, they are not just "alternative spellings."  One includes the *niqqud* (vowel pointings, cantillation marks, tone marks, etc.) while the other includes only the original consonants.  This will be important when searching for a word.  The niqqud can make finding every occurrence of a Hebrew word quite difficult.

For example, all of the following are various forms of "adonai" in Hebrew.
אֲדֹנָי֙

אֲדֹנָ֖י

אֲדֹנָ֕י

אֲדֹנָֽי

אדֹנָי֙

אֲדֹנָ֔י

אֲדֹנָ֗י

אֲדֹנָ֑י

אֲדֹנָ֥י

אֲ֝דֹנָ֗י

Matching any one of those will mean finding only a subset of all of the "adonai" occurrences.  But if we strip away the niqqud, we can search on just the root letters and potentially find *every* occurrence.

My assumption would be that the website includes both forms for its own search/find functionality, as well as to facilitate better access to online search engines.

Comment: tbh I think the fact one is plene (using matres lectionis) is more relevant than the fact one uses niqqud. Niqqud are easily ignored either by a human (as they are, for the most part, obviously secondary to the full letters) or by a machine (with a simple regular expression). Matres lectionis are trickier though as they are full letters that appear in the unpointed spelling, but not in the pointed one and so naive attempts to convert between spelling systems will fail

Comment: consider קידוש / קִדּוּשׁ kiddush. Looking at the pointed spelling and stripping away all niqqud we'd expect קדש (note that וּ is a shuruk here, and not a vav dagesh, as can be seen due to the lack of any other niqqud on the qaf) as the corresponding unpointed spelling. Going in the other direction we'd expect the yod and vav of the plene spelling to take vowel diacritics when they do not, and in one instance the consonant letter vanishes altogether! The exact same thing of a mater lectionis being present in the unpointed spelling but not the pointed one is in the OP's example

Comment: @Tristan Good points, and valuable.  I should have mentioned te'amim as well, as that is a little broader than niqqud.  But the early forms of matres lectionis would be more difficult to accommodate algorithmically, as they do appear like regular root letters in the word, as you note.  However, niqqud is not merely vowel pointings: it includes dagesh, the dot on sin/shin, etc.

Comment: sure. My main point is the fact that pointed spelling is usually defective, and unpointed spelling usually plene means that there are full letters that differ between the two and there's not a simple way to tell which vav's and yod's are matres lectionis, and which are consonants. Only the vowel pointings factor into that equation. Te'amim are also much less relevant as (with the exception of meteg) they are not lexical, but syntactic/prosodic